# App.js giving error while connecting mongoDB Atlas Cloud

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

When i am trying to run app.js while connecting mongoDB atlas cloud, its ginving me error..

Operation `items.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms.

While connecting with localhost it's working perfectly.

can any one help me to resolved this?

```
//jshint esversion:6

const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://****:****@cluster0.tzmxqm3.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority/todolistDB";

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client
      .connect()
      .then(() => console.log("connected"))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

you specify the name of the database at the end, so you set w param to 'majority/todolistDB', which is not correct in theory, instead try

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://****:****@cluster0.tzmxqm3.mongodb.net/todolistDBretryWrites=true&w=majority";
```